# Getting the displayed image out of an NSImageCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview, nsimage

I have an `NSImageCell` table column whose `valuePath` is bound to a path supplied by my object through an `NSArrayController`.

My `NSTableViewDelegate` implements the `-tableView:heightOfRow:` method, in order to have variable row height. I need to calculate row height based on the dimensions of the image displayed in the aforementioned column.

Right now, I'm getting horrible performance, though, since I'm calling `[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:<path>]` for each iteration. Is there any way to load the image representation that each `NSImageCell` has already retrieved for display?

I'm happy with the performance exhibited by using the `valuePath` binding, and would rather not cache each image on my own, as there will be many of them, each somewhat large.

I tried the `NSTableColumn` method `-dataCellForRow:`, which sounded perfect, except the cell returned returns an `objectValue` that seems to be the last row for which data was loaded.

**Update (solution, unsatisfactory)**

I figured out an approximate solution (posted simultaneously below), but it seems clumsy (and I've already seen it fail at random, irreproducible times), and I am still looking for a better solution.

I'm using the `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` delegate method to populate a mutable dictionary with `[[cell objectValue] size]` (the image's size) keyed to the represented object's unique ID. Then, in the `-tableView:heightOfRow:` call I'm looking up the cover from this dictionary. I need to call `[tableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged]` after data is loaded, otherwise the dictionary isn't filled properly for the initial screen of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried the NSTableColumn method -dataCellForRow:, which sounded perfect, except the cell returned returns an objectValue that seems to be the last row for which data was loaded.

That's because the `NSTableColumn` only uses a single data cell for displaying the entire column, swapping out its value as it draws.

If I were you, I would probably try implementing the [`– tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008622) method in your `NSTableViewDelegate`. Then you can intercept the cell before it's about to be drawn, get its value at that moment, and cache just its height (as an `NSNumber*` or `CGFloat`). Then you can return *that* value in `-tableView:heightOfRow:`.

Then again, it's possible that `-tableView:heightOfRow:` gets called before `– tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`, so that might not work. I'm not sure. But that's where I would start.